# JavaScript boolean compare always fails

Tags: javascript, extjs4, boolean

This Boolean comparison always returns false but it is comparing false == false in my getColumnsFunction().  It should return true, and I have no clue why.  Here is the code:

```
function getModelColumns(exlude, modelName){    
    var model = Ext.ModelManager.getModel(modelName).create();
    var fields = model.fields.items;

    for(var x in fields){
        console.log( inArray(exlude, fields[x].name == false),
                    'boolean_compare', 
                     inArray(exlude, fields[x].name));
     }

}
function inArray(arr,val){
    for(var x in arr){
        if(arr[x] === val)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Here is what is in console.log() for all fields in that for loop:

```
false "boolean_compare" false
```

They are both equal to false, why they heck does that boolean comparison return false?

Edit: forgot a '(' it should be  inArray(exlude, fields[x].name ) == false

Comment: Don't use `for … in` to iterate over array elements. Use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: Where is the actual comparison in your code?

Comment: @FabioCosta: In the `console.log` line: `fields[x].name == false` and `fields[x].name`.

Comment: Are you sure that `val` is within `exlude`?

Comment: Is the value `fields[x].name` really a boolean?

Comment: You should read up on the very significant difference between an **array** and an **object** in JavaScript.  An  Array is a particular type of Object, but not all Objects are Arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression:

```
inArray(exlude, fields[x].name == false)
```

will first compare the name to `false`, and as they are not equal it will call `inArray(exclude, false)`. Unless it's an array containing the value `false` it will always return false.

I think that you want:

```
inArray(exlude, fields[x].name) == false
```

which will search for the name in the array, then compare the result to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the field name is not explicit defined as boolean, so in extjs by default is string. You are comparing `"false"` with `false` .

Comment: ya this might be it test it please

Answer (score 0):

you can debug with firebug on FF or web tools on Chrome i would do it. 
but give us jsfiddle demo on it  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

but i think may be console.log has something to do with it i got same problem one dont use console.log use alert test it .